# Get the drawable's name after setting it on ImageView

Tags: android, image, random, drawable

I'am Actually setting an image to the ImageView Dynamically from the Drawable folder. I got the working code to set the image dynamically but I can't get the name of the image/drawable which gets set on the image view at the moment.
 Either I should get the drawable name or any code to get the instance of each drawable with a name which I can set on the ImageView.
Any help is Much Appreciated!!

I searched and tried all answers on StackOverflow.

Set the image dynamically to the imageview and also get that image's name.

Comment: can you please post code , how you are doing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. after 2 days of research and trials, I finally managed to do what I planned to do. Here's my code, if anybody gets help from it.

```
ArrayList<Integer> array_fruits = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int fruit_apricot = R.drawable.fruits_apricot;
    int fruit_apple = R.drawable.fruits_apple;
    int fruit_banana = R.drawable.fruits_banana;
```

.... and more

```
array_fruits.add(fruit_apple);
        array_fruits.add(fruit_apricot);
        array_fruits.add(fruit_banana);
```

... and more

//WORKING CODE TO GENERATE NUMBER BETWEEN 30 AND 1 (0 to 29 in arraylist)

```
Random rand = new Random();
                    int num = rand.nextInt(30) + 1;
                    array_fruits.add(num);
                    itemImg.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(array_fruits.get(num)));
                    Log.e("num: ", num+"");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), num+"", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

I had tried almost all solutions given on stackoverflow and other sites.

Answer (score 0):

As a good practice, you can store the drawable in a variable and update the imageview.

```
@DrawableRes int myDrawable;
iv.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(myDrawable));
```

Setting tag and getting from tag is no ideal imho because it's more maintainable and debuggable.